# Full text and tagged search in web application. What are my options?

Tags: c#, asp.net, full-text-search, search-engine

I need to search articles by text and tags on my web site. What are my options in doing that?
Can I use services like Google Custom Search? Do I need fulltext search engine? Other solutions? What are the pros and cons?
I need results ranking by relevance. Also it would be great to have features like query preiction, suggestion, related searches

Comment: What is your solution now dude?

Comment: @tdat00, I think I will do it with Elasticsearch. It does everything I want and has nice RESTful API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research (and thanks for the answers!) here's what I found

- MS SQL full text index
  It gives me search by full text and tags, but leaves up to me to implement the rest (suggestions, highlighting etc).
- Elasticsearch engine
  It gives me search by full text and tags, suggestions, highlighting and everything. But I need to populate the index and keep it in sync with main database.

Google Site Search is not an option. It cannot search only articles and nothing else. It cannot search by tags. (Though , I didn't check that)

As for Lucene.Net, Elasticsearch is built on Lucene and handles many more issues for me. Plus it has nice RESTful API.

Right now I am experimenting with Elasticsearch. I think I will use it for the feature.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is SQL Server, then you can enable `full-text index` by right clicking on the table name in object explorer in SQL Server Management Studio and selecting `Full-Text Index` as shown in screen shot below. The table on which full-text search needs to be enabled must have a `unique index`  else this will not work.

Once you have created the full-text index on columns of your choice, you can use special full-text search functions in your query. You can read about how to query at following URLs: [MSDN Full-text Search Queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583(v=sql.105).aspx) and [Full-text Search in SQL Server](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sample-full-text-search-engine)`

[image: Full-text Index in SQL Server]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lucence.Net](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx) for that. It's open source, supported ranking full-text search... All you need is just provide your raw text(s) to its indexer; when you search something, it will show you the most relevance entries related to your pattern.

The cost is that it will index your data into a directory instead of reuse SQL database. So you need to sync/rebuild its index when you updated your database.